# SQL decimals inaccurate for floating point value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, floating-point

Currently I have the following code:

```
Declare @FloatVal float
set @FloatVal = 777777111111.555343
print @FloatVal
print @FloatVal - FLOOR(@FloatVal)
select @FloatVal
select @FloatVal - FLOOR(@FloatVal)
```

And it outputs 7.77777e+011 for the first print, 0.555298 for the second print, 777777111111.556 for the first select and it outputs 0.5552978515625 for the second select.  Why is this the case?  Ultimately we want to receive the decimal places accurately, however, it seems to never give us this.  Unfortunately we cannot change the datatype from float to anything else because the system is setup in a way where this is not possible.

Thank you

Comment: If you want exact decimal places you must use a `DECIMAL`. A `FLOAT` has approx. 15 digits accuracy and a `DECIMAL` exactly up to 38.

Comment: Therefore, is there any way to convert this value to a decimal without losing any of the digits?  Like I said, I must have it originally be a float because that is how the server is set up and it is so big this cannot be changed

Comment: No, because you can't store a number with 18 digits precision in a FLOAT.